# Change url parameter in htaccess using regex

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I have pages with the following parameters: `/article.php?sid=123&cat1=en`

I need to change that `cat1` to `cat` and redirect to the same address.

I've tried `RewriteRule ^/article.php?sid=(.*)&cat1=(.*)$ /article.php?sid=$1&cat=$2 [R=301,L]` but it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule to match & replace a given query parameter at any position.

Keep this rule as your very first rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*&)?cat1=([^&]*(?:&.*)?)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^article\.php$ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1cat=%2 [R=301,NE,L]
```

Comment: thanks. How would I go around if I had just one parameter say: /article.php?cat1=en?

Comment: I made a minor update. `http://localhost/article.php?cat1=en` will be redirected to `http://localhost/article.php?cat=en`